# React-native android toolbar going below status bar

Tags: react-native, material-ui

I am trying to set a status bar colour in react native. I am using [react-native-material-ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui) for the toolbar component. My problem is that whenever I am setting status bar colour, the toolbar is moving up and below the status bar.
See the screenshots below:
[image]

I am using the following:

```
const uiTheme = {
    palette: {
        primaryColor: COLOR.green500
    },
    toolbar: {
        container: {
            height: 56
        }
    }
};

export default class RecentChatListScreen extends Component
{
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider uiTheme={uiTheme}>
                <View>
                    <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)" translucent />
                    <Toolbar
                        leftElement="menu"
                        centerElement="Hola"
                        searchable={{
                            autoFocus: true,
                            placeholder: 'Search your chats',
                        }}
                        onLeftElementPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
                    />
                    <Text>List of recent chats.</Text>
                    <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Chat')} title="Go to Chat"/>
                </View>
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping Toolbar, Text and Button inside another View?

Comment: @Srijith yes, I did but unfortunately nothing happened.

Comment: Can someone care to tell me why its down voted? I would love to improve the question if its not understandable.

Comment: What is your uiTheme?

Comment: @Srijith updated question

Comment: Check this https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui/issues/91

Comment: I went through this issue before posting this question as it didnt address my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the demo app [here](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui-demo-app/blob/master/src/App/App.react.js#L26) you should use a view of statusbar's height to avoid overlay. Like the code below after `StatusBar`:

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: COLOR.green500, height: 24 }} />
```

Comment: Ok I will try this and inform. Btw What about on IOS?

Comment: It's working but how do I adjust for IOS and iPhone X?

Answer (score 3):

In case any one facing the issue with expo, just add "paddingTop: Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight" in the root view of your App component

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      //other components 
      </View>)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Expo-specific code, use the constant provided by react-native, in StatusBar. [According to the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar#constants), `StatusBar.currentHeight` is only provided for Android implementations. I have not verified that the iOS version returns 0 versus undefined.

```js
const uiTheme = {
    palette: {
        primaryColor: COLOR.green500
    },
    toolbar: {
        container: {
            height: 56,
            paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0
        }
    }
};
```